# Getting a String value from NSOrderedSet using SwiftUI ForEach

Tags: swift, core-data, foreach, swiftui, nsorderedset

Using [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58759409/nsorderedset-and-swiftui-foreach) I am able to use ForEach to use a NSOrderedSet created from a One to Many relationship in CoreData, however I can't seem to access a String Attribute stored in the Core Data entity.

I have two CoreData entities: Client & SessionNote. Clients can have many SessionNotes, the NSOrderedSet of clientNotes, and SessionNote can only have one Client.

Client+CoreDataClass.swift:

```
public class Client: NSManagedObject {

}
```

Client+CoreDataProperties.swift:

```
extension Client {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Client> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Client>(entityName: "Client")
    }

    @NSManaged public var firstName: String?
    @NSManaged public var lastName: String?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var clientNotes: NSOrderedSet?

}
```

SessionNote+CoreDataClass.swift:

```
public class SessionNote: NSManagedObject {

}
```

SessionNote+CoreDataProperties.swift:

```
extension SessionNote {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<SessionNote> {
        return NSFetchRequest<SessionNote>(entityName: "SessionNote")
    }

    @NSManaged public var date: Date?
    @NSManaged public var noteText: String?
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID?
    @NSManaged public var clientOrigin: Client?

}
```

and here is ClientDetailView.swift:

```
struct ClientDetailView: View {

    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc

    @ObservedObject var selectedClient: Client


    var body: some View {
        Form {
            HStack {
                Text("\(selectedClient.firstName ?? "") \(selectedClient.lastName ?? "")")
            }
            Section() {
                ForEach(Array(selectedClient.clientNotes!.set), id: \.self) { note in
                    Text("This will repeat for the number of notes in the clientNotes NSOrderedSet")
                    /*
                     But instead I want to be able to display the noteText
                     string attribute stored in the SessionNote CoreData entity
                     instead of the above placeholder.
                    */
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I've tried `Text("\(note.noteText ?? "")")` but it throws the following error:

> Value of type 'AnyHashable' has no member 'noteText'

When I tried `Text("\(self.selectedClient.clientNotes!.value(forKeyPath: \SessionNote.noteText))")` it throws the following error:

> Protocol type 'Any' cannot conform to '_FormatSpecifiable' because only concrete types can conform to protocols

Is there anyway to display the different String values for each of the SessionNote noteText entity?

Comment: try `Text(note as? SessionNote)?.noteText ?? "")`

Comment: This also worked. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome `Text((note as? SessionNote)?.noteText ?? "")` there was a missing parentheses. You might also be interest in https://github.com/leodabus/OrderedSet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `array` method on `NSOrderedSet` and force typecast it to `[SessionNote]`, since you know that you will always be storing `SessionNote` class to the ordered set.

```
ForEach(selectedClient.clientNotes!.array as! [SessionNote], id: \.self) { (note: SessionNote) in
    Text(note.text ?? "")
}
```

Since this casting will be necessary in every places you wish to use the notes. You could also add a computed property inside your `Client` which always gives you typed version of the `SessionNote` array.

```
extension Client {
  var typedClientNotes: [SessionNote] {
    return (clientNotes?.array as? [SessionNote]) ?? []
  }
}
```

And, with these new changes you can make your `ForEach` bit better.

```
ForEach(selectedClient.typedClientNotes, id: \.self) { note in
    Text(note.text ?? "")
}
```

For this reason, I try to use normal `Set` for Core data relationship. Because it can be typed and makes working with Coredata so much fun. But, `NSOrderedSet` has its own advantages despite of being an untyped collection.

Comment: Thank you! This did it.