# How to ForEach in SwiftUI a NSOrderedSet from FetchedResults (CoreData)

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, nsorderedset

I am trying to use ForEach in SwiftUI with my NSOrderedSet with comes from a FetchedResult.
Tried already the following code (from this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58983303/getting-a-string-value-from-nsorderedset-using-swiftui-foreach))

withChilds is a relationship definied (Core Data - one Card has many childs).

**In Card:**

```
@NSManaged public var withChilds: NSOrderedSet?
```

**My View Code**

```
struct Test: View {
        @FetchRequest(entity: Card.entity(),
                  sortDescriptors: [],
                  predicate: nil)
    var cards: FetchedResults<Card>

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Text("count: \(cards[0].withChilds?.count)") //first entity on purpose

            ScrollView {
                ForEach(cards){  card in
                    ForEach(Array(card.withChilds!.set), id: \.self) { child in //**ERROR**
                        //Text("someText: \(child.text1)")
                    }   
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error code
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlighted error is because there is no view specified in `ForEach`, so if to define something static, like

```
ForEach(Array(card.withChilds!.set), id: \.self) { child in 
        Text("Just test")
    }
```

there should be no error (tested with Xcode 11.4)

But there is no specified what is inside that `NSOrderedSet`, so if suppose it is instances of `Child` class then the following tested works

```
ForEach(Array(card.withChilds!.set), id: \.self) { child in 
        Text("someText: \((child as! Child).text1)")
    }
```