# How to reuse the same SwiftUI ForEach structure for NSOrderedSet and FetchedResults

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-protocols

I have a SwiftUI view where the bulk of the logic displays a list of recipes with a `LazyVGrid`. The code looks something like this:

```swift
struct RecipeGrid: View {
    let recipes: [Recipe]
    var body: some View {
        return LazyVGrid {
            ForEach(countries) { country in 
                Text(recipe.title)
            }
        }
     }
}
```

This is the hello world of SwiftUI. Straightforward stuff. Two real-world requirements make things a bit more interesting/challenging.

First, we have over 20,000 recipes. So we don't want to pass everything in as an array, as suggested by [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58759409/nsorderedset-and-swiftui-foreach) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61803803/how-to-foreach-in-swiftui-a-nsorderedset-from-fetchedresults-coredata).

Second, there are two different ways we get the `recipes`.

The first is to show the most popular recipes using a `FetchRequest`. It looks something like this:

```swift
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [SortDescriptor(\.likes, order: .reverse)])
private var recipes: FetchedResults<Recipe>
```

The second is to get all recipes using the same ingredient. There is a ManyToMany relationship between `Ingredient` and `Recipe`. The declaration of `Ingredients` looks like this:

```swift
class Ingredient: Entity {
    @NSManaged var recipes: NSOrderedSet
}
```

I am wondering what would be the recommended way to declare the `recipes` inside `RecipeGrid` so that it will support both the use cases above.

I have tried the following

```swift
struct RecipeGrid: View {
    let recipes: RandomAccessCollection
    ...
}
```

The above doesn't work. Swift gives the following error message: `Protocol 'RandomAccessCollection' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`.

What is the best practice way to approach this? I guess another way to ask my question is:

***How do I declare the associated type for RandomAccessCollection?***

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/61495490/12299030?

Comment: @Jessy `OrderedSet` has many nice properties, including built-in conformance to `RandomAccessCollection`. Sadly, I can't seem to make it work with CoreData's `@NSManaged`. Context: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73114442/is-it-possible-to-use-swift-collections-orderedset-to-represent-a-coredata

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Asperi's help. I figured out a way to achieve what I had in mind.

There are two parts to the answer.

The first is to rewrite `RecipeGrid`'s signature to bind to the `RandomAccessCollection` protocol, Based on [passing `FetchedResult` to Preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61495141/passing-core-data-fetchedresultst-for-previews-in-swiftui/61495490#61495490).
This opens up the possibility to test the view using an array and `FetchedResult`.

```swift
struct RecipeGrid<Recipes: RandomAccessCollection>: View where RandomAccessCollection.Element == Recipe {
  let recipes: Recipes
  ...
}
```

The second part is to give up using the CoreData relationship `Ingredient.recipes`. The `recipes` is of type `NSOrderedSet`, which does not conform to the `RandomAccessCollection` protocol.

The `swift-collections`' `OrderedSet` does support `RandomAccessCollection` but unfortunately [it doesn't work with CoreData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73114442/is-it-possible-to-use-swift-collections-orderedset-to-represent-a-coredata-one/73114469).

I rewrote the code to have a second `FetchedResult` to replace the `ingredient.recipes` call.