# Is it possible to use swift-collections' OrderedSet to represent a CoreData One-to-Many relationship?

Tags: swift, core-data

The `OrderedSet` in `swift-collections` has many desirable properties.
But I can't quite figure out how to, or whether it is possible to, use it to replace the `NSOrderedSet` to represent a relationship in CoreData entities.

Consider the following entity:

```swift
@objc(Ingredient)
class Ingredient: Entity {
    @NSManaged var recipes: NSOrderedSet
}
```

The code won't compile if I change it to use `OrderedSet` like the following

```swift
import OrderedCollections
class Ingredient: Entity {
    @NSManaged var recipes: OrderedSet<Recipe>
}
```

The error message is `error build: Property cannot be marked @NSManaged because its type cannot be represented in Objective-C`.

Answer (score 2):

> But I can't quite figure out how to use it to replace the NSOrderedSet to represent a relationship in CoreData entities.

Because it can't be done. Swift OrderedSet is totally unrelated to Cocoa / Objective-C NSOrderedSet. The former is so you don't have to use the latter, but you are talking to Core Data so you *do* have to use the latter.

Comment: I suppose it might be possible write a reducer but it seems hardly worth the trouble of thinking about, even.

Comment: Hey @Matt, thank you for the quick response. That makes sense. I was just wondering if I have missed something.

Comment: Yeah, you probably think that because there is Set/NSSet there should be OrderedSet/NSOrderedSet. But there isn't. OrderedSet is not a "front" for NSOrderedSet, like Set/NSSet or Date/NSDate; it's a totally independent being.